# Merge text files with same first line

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to merge multiple text files into one text file, I tried using:

```
For %f in (*.txt) Do type "%f" >> onetext.txt
```

what I need it to do is make sure it merges the files with the same first line first and then merge the remaining files. Here is an example of whats inside some of the files:

```
Name1
Data 1
Data 2

Name2
Data 1
Data 2

Name1
Data 3
Data 4
```

What I need to ultimately get is:

```
Name1
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
Data 4

Name2
Data 1
Data 2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del *.out
del summary.txt
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  <%%i set /p first=
  if not exist !first!.out (echo/&echo Title: !first!)>!first!.out
  more +1 %%i >>!first!.out
) 
type *.out >summary.txt 2>nul
type summary.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand, you want a single outputfile. See my edit.

Comment: Maybe. How to decide, where to set the linefeeds? Title always one word? How many words per data-line? Is it the same for every data-line? Or do they all start with the same word ("Data")? When there is no fixed rule to split the line, you're lost.

Comment: Good. That means, we can isolate the title. How about the Data-Lines? How to know, where one Dataset ends and the next starts?